# A Box of Puzzle Blocks

Tags: geometry, optimization

A cubical box is required to contain a set of wooden blocks (N right parallelepiped solids that fits in without spaces) which have different edges and colors. No two blocks have the same edge linear measurement. All blocks have unique dimension (integer units), thus no square faces.

> **What are the smallest box's inside dimensions SxSxS  ?**

Comment: Are you looking for a solution involving $n$ solids fitting the constraints?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to clarify: a dimensionless box is enough to contain (and exactly fit) an empty set of 1x2x3 blocks. A 3x3x3 box is enough to contain a single 1x2x3 block. Yes, there's space left over, but filling the box isn't a stated requirement. Does the "dimensional measurement" mean volume, side length, side area, total area or maybe all of the above? Also, what do the colours have to do with anything?

Comment: "No two blocks has the same dimensional measurement" Does that mean no two blocks have a common side length, or no two blocks are congruent, or no two blocks have the same volume?

Comment: What do you mean by "inside dimensions"? As opposed to outside dimensions?

Comment: No two blocks has common edge or side distance..and box haa thickness

Comment: @bass-Like ordinary colored  blocks for distinction. Block set would be W1xL1xH1, W2xL2xH2, W3xH3xL3..so on. All dimensions are unique integer

Comment: Disclaimer: above was ask by a friend in reply to my post  "Square Room Tiles"

Comment: Link: [Square Room Tiles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52891/square-room-tiles)

Comment: I’m assuming this is intended to be the three-dimensional analog to the Square Room Tiles puzzle, but it doesn’t actually *say* that. And should be self-contained anyway, not relying on solvers extrapolating the intended rules from the previous puzzle.  Please add clarifications to this puzzle statement to, for example, make it clear that there are no duplicate lengths in the set of *all* edge lengths of *all* blocks, and that the requirement is to fully occupy a cubic volume SxSxS with no gaps. Or, if those are not the requirements, to accurately give what they are.

Comment: Op states that 'no two blocks having the same edge linear measurement' instead of edge length since blocks has length, width and height for it may create another clarifications. also stated they fit in (box) without spaces so must fully occupy the box volume

Answer (score 3):

> 4x4x4

Because

> Given there was no constraint to the number of right parallelepipeds, I chose two. Since each solid has pairwise unique side length (and it was not specified that we could not have repeats between solids), the solids in the box have dimension 1x2x3 and 1x2x4. These clearly fit within a 4x4x4 box.

And if side length is pairwise unique between all solids,

> 7x7x7 with solids 1x2x3 and 4x5x6, which again clearly fit. (Originally said 6x6x6, derp.)

Comment: Yeah, thats why I added an answer that considers that constraint (which is not clearly stated).

Comment: Derp, 7x7x7 obviously. Thanks. I still dont really understand what the problem really is though lol.

Comment: Yeah thats what I assumed in my first answer.

Comment: I didn't assume that the solids fit together to have the same dimensions of the box. I assumed we could just put two of them in the box. It wasn't specified in the problem, another issue with its construction.

Comment: I'll stop commenting until the question is clarified.  At this point, I neither know what the objective is nor do I know what the constraints are.